# Name for ongoing syntactic dependencies after a word

Tags: computational-linguistics, syntax-trees, dependency-grammar

[image: a syntactic network of a short sentence]

Consider the sentence "I love my dog." There are three syntactic dependencies in this sentence: (a) the subject dependency from "I" to "love," (b) the modifier dependency from "my" to "dog," and (c) the object dependency from "dog" to "love." If we count the number of dependencies that are active after each word, we get 1 for "I" (dependency a), 1 for "love" (dependency c), 2 for "my" (dependencies b and c) and 0 for "dog." Is there a name for the thing we just counted? (It's not the depth of each node in the graph, although in this brief example depth and this other feature are the same.) This isn't my field, so my apologies if it's something you'd expect anyone with an interest in this topic to know off-hand.

Comment: Not my field, but I don't understand "the number of dependencies that are active after each word"

Comment: If you visualize a vertical line after each word, that line would cross 1 arch after "I", 1 after "love", and 2 after "my". (And none after "dog").

Comment: That sounds like Arc Pair grammar/

Comment: I think the most helpful term to use to characterize what the question is asking about is _center embedding_. If the tree grows mainly downward, the depth becomes great and the processing very difficult. The more center embedding, the more difficult the sentence is to process.

Answer (score 3):

In [dependency grammar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_grammar) there is the *valency* of a verb, the number of dependencies it can have. So *love* has a valency of two: the subject and one object. But this is slightly different from your interpretation of 'dependency': there, the verb is at the centre. The dependencies you describe seem rather strange in that context.

What you seem to mean is the 'depth' of dependency, or the distance from the main item. I am not aware of any specific term for this.

Comment: I do not think "depth" is the correct characterization. If the branching is entirely down and to the right, the number of dependencies at the deepest node will still be zero. What the question is characterizing is, rather, the extent to which there is center-embedding, i.e. zig-zagging in the dependency structure.

Comment: @TimOsborne As far as I remember there is no such thing as center-embedding in dependency grammar. That is a matter of the linearisation of the dependency structure into a sequential list of words. 
But this doesn’t seem to be a ‘proper’ dependency structure, so perhaps you are correct.